# What does this mean "prvalue of type“ in C++ standard N3337 5.2.10 clause 7?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast, prvalue

In [C++ draft standard N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/) section [5.2.10 `Reinterpret cast` clause 7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) (*emphasis mine*):

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer to a different type. When **a prvalue v of type** “pointer to T1” is converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))`  if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment
>   requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void.

Does this mean that the expression `v` is a prvalue?. If so, then

```
int a = 0x1234;
int *pa = &a;
char *pc = reinterpret_cast<char *>(pa);
```

Above,the variable `pa` is an `lvalue`, so can we think if a variable of `lvalue` is in the right expression, the variable is a `prvalue` of type?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification uses `v` to represent an expression. It is not necessarily a name of a variable.

In your example, the paragraph you referred to does not apply directly because `pa` is an lvalue. Instead, the [lvalue-to-rvalue conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.lval) is applied firstly, then this paragraph applies.

Comment: Thank you, my understanding for the [5.2.10 `Reinterpret cast` clause 7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#7)  is listed below. First, the `reinterpret_cast<T>(v)` expects the `v` is a prvalue ,that is a subexpression appeared in the right of expression is expected as a prvalue. Second, [5 Expressions clause 8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#8) and [4.1  Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion clause 1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.lval#1)explain the conversion is correct. Do I understand correctly above?

Answer (score 2):

cppreference is your friend here, if we go to the topic [Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) it tell us a *prvalue* is:

> a prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an expression whose evaluation either
>
> - computes the value of the operand of an operator (such prvalue has no result object), or
> - initializes an object or a bit-field (such prvalue is said to have a result object). All class and array prvalues have a result object even if it is discarded. In certain contexts, temporary materialization occurs to create a temporary as the result object;

Which is not automatically enlightening but they provide a very nice set of [examples below](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue) I will quote some of the pointer examples:

> The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> ...
>
> - &a, the built-in address-of expression;
>   ...
> - the this pointer;
>   ....

So casting a *this* pointer or the result of address-of to a const of the pointer of that type would fit the wording (assuming that it was not already const) e.g.:

```
{
  int x = 0;
  const int *p = reinterpret_cast<const int*>(&x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what you say don't suit in here.